# vue-ckeditor5 setEventListener Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Using vue-ckeditor5.
Simple call

```
<ckeditor type="classic" v-model="details"></ckeditor>
```

Import the needed modules

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
import VueCkeditor from 'vue-ckeditor5'
const options = {
  editors: {
    classic: ClassicEditor,
  },
  name: 'ckeditor'
}

Vue.use(VueCkeditor.plugin, options);
```

Set my data to bind

```
details: "These are details",
```

When I open the page I get the page with the editor showing. But no data is displayed.
Error that I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys
> () at VueComponent.setEventListeners
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-ckeditor5/dist/vue-ckeditor5.js:1)
> at eval
> (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-ckeditor5/dist/vue-ckeditor5.js:1)

Issue seems to be in the setEventListener method

```
setEventListeners: function() {
                    var e = this
                      , t = this.instance;
                    if (null != t) {
                        t.model.document.on("change:data", (function() {
                            var n = t.getData();
                            if (e.value !== n) {
                                e.emptyValueProvided && e.isEmpty && (n = e.emptyValue);
                                for (var r = arguments.length, o = new Array(r), i = 0; i < r; i++)
                                    o[i] = arguments[i];
                                e.$emit.apply(e, ["input", n, t].concat(o))
                            }
                        }
                        ));
                        for (var n = t.editing.view.document, r = n._events, o = function() {
                            var r = u[i];
                            n.on(r, (function() {
                                for (var n = arguments.length, o = new Array(n), i = 0; i < n; i++)
                                    o[i] = arguments[i];
                                e.$emit.apply(e, [r, t].concat(o))
                            }
                            ))
                        }, i = 0, u = Object.keys(r); i < u.length; i++)
                            o()
                    }
                }
```

Not sure why the error and why "These are details" does not get displayed

Comment: is that `setEventListeners` something you wrote? if not, it's probably something in your code passing in an incorrect value - but, since you didn't post very much of your code at all, and what you posted doesn't look like much of `vue` at all, it's going to be difficult to help - and since the error is with `setEventListener` then the function `setEventListeners` is not going to be the problem

Comment: Package [vue-ckeditor5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-ckeditor5) was last updated 2 years ago and clearly states that it is outdated and you should use [official release](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue)